# Model training when calculating training error and cross-validation error

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to calculate training error and cross validation error for the same training set.

Model: RandomForestRegressor 
Metrics: Training error -> RMSE, Cross validation error -> k fold cross validation

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

forest_reg = RandomForestRegressor()
scores = cross_val_score(forest_reg, X_train_transformed, y_train,
                         scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)
tree_rmse_scores = np.sqrt(-scores)
print(tree_rmse_scores.mean())

forest_reg = RandomForestRegressor()
forest_reg.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train)
error = mean_squared_error(y_train, forest_reg.predict(X_train_transformed))
print(error)
```

My understanding is that model has to be trained explicitly when calculating training error but for cross val score, model is fitted for every k-1 folds and validated on 1 fold for k times. In this case, no explicit fitting is not required before calling cross_val_score().

Any issue with above code? I'm getting huge training error than CV error. Is my above understanding incorrect?

Comment: What do you mean by  `trained explicitly` and no `explicit fitting`, `k-1` folds `k=1`, same as validate the entire training set, so it's does nothing, the choice of k usually should be `k>2` ,at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to take the square root of the MSE in the approach without CV:

```
forest_reg = RandomForestRegressor()
forest_reg.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train)
error = mean_squared_error(y_train, forest_reg.predict(X_train_transformed))
print(np.sqrt(error)) # <-- take the square root here or already above
```

The difference was so huge because you compared RMSE with MSE. Now you should see what you expected.

Comment: thats true. thanks for the answer. Also, is my understanding correct on the process of training model for linear regression (training error) and Random forest (CV error)?

Comment: There is no linear regression in your example. Maybe something got mixed up here? Anyway, you were in general right with your understanding. Repeated model fitting and testing with _k_ folds is part of the `cross_val_score` function and there is no need to call `.fit()` on the model before. If you do not use such pre-implemented functionalities, you have to call `.fit()` before any custom evaluation. Your description of k-fold cross-validation was also okay. So your understanding was overall alright.

Answer (score 0):

How much larger than validation error?
Isn't it natural that training error is larger than validation error with or without it is just 'validation' or 'cross validataion'.

Comment: I don't think training error can be larger than cross validation in any case, because model was trained and tested on same set in case of training error.

Comment: Sure, it is not any case.

Comment: And there can be many reasons with higher training error like as imbalanced dataset, very small validation data comparing to train set, etc.